# Renci.SshNet Async SFTP file download does work intermittently

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, async-await

I have written the code below to download files using `SftpClient` from the `Renci.SshNet` library. The code works fine when I download two files at a time, but fails when I try to download three or more files. I'm using AWS Lambda to process the files, and the error message I get when attempting to download three files at once is not very informative:

```
Exception: {"@t":"2023-06-16T04:40:34.497894Z","@m":"Downloader failed. Exception: ʹʺRenci.SshNet.Common.SshException: General failure: null\n at Renci.SshNet.Common.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()\n at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.EndDownloadFile(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n at SftpClient.DownloadFile(String path)\n at GenericFileTransfer.Services.DownloadService.HandleFile(String path)\n at GenericFileTransfer.Services.DownloadService.DownloadAllFiles(String directory)\n at LambdaFunctions.Downloader.DownloadFunction.DownloadHandlerAsync(Input input)ʺʹ","@i":"223fd601","@l":"Fatal","SourceContext":"None","Application":"Aws.Common.GenericFileTransfer"}
```

Can someone guide me?

Here's my current code:

```cs
public virtual async Task<Stream> DownloadFile(string path)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            _sftpClient.BeginDownloadFile(path, output),
            _sftpClient.EndDownloadFile);
        return output;
    }
    catch
    {
        await output.DisposeAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate, if someone could help, please.